# Capture video from playing video on Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture video from a playing video (not from the camera) on Android? I mean, that it records a video from surface video output.

As far as I know, mediaRecorder can record it only from Camera. But, I'm trying to trim a video for a specific range while it plays this video.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it probable that this is something you want to tackle? Probably not. This idea is not original. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tcy5zY3JlZW5jYXN0Il0.

Comment: Also if you have access to the data of the video, you can manipulate/copy it. But it sounds like this is not what you want, and this doesn't sound like a fun time either ;)